# Runtime binding ejb bean in JNDI

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jndi, apache-tomee

I have problem with EJB Session bean in modular applications.

My Question is : 
How can bind new Local EJB bean when JavaEE application server (Like: Jboss Or TomEE) is running ?

Maybe my question has problem or my thinking is wrong about EJB beans.
I search in internet(Google) for this but can not find answer .  (Maybe search key word has problem !)

========================
**Update :**
Example Code :

```
@Local
public interface Hello {
    void sayHello() ;
}
```

and implementation :

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class HelloService implements Hello {

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I package this code to jar file . 
Now I start jboss application server and in my webapp upload this jar file to directory named modules in server .

so ,Jar file only uploaded on server **at runtime** , I wont restart application server (JBOSS) for register this stateless bean on server .

**1)** How can register (Load) this stateless object on server ?
**2)** How can unregister (unload) this object ?

Thank you .

Comment: EJB should already be registered in JNDI at load time due to the annotation.  you just need to inject it where it is needed.  unless your purpose is different to the usual case.  do you have any code example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated post ...

Comment: during upload the server will register the stateless?  then it will be unregistered when container stops.  sorry i am not familiar with deploying jar modules

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve that can't be done by deploying normally?

Comment: Question is : Can load ejb module at runtime (without restart application server)? if yes : How ?